# lambda task timed out error while using rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-rekognition

I'm building a React native app with serverless framework using AWS services.

I created a  RESTapi with lambda function (nodeJs8.10 environment) and API gateway to use rekognition services such as indexFaces, listCollection, etc. My lambda is in VPC with RDS( later I'll Aurora) to store faceID and other data.
Everything works fine except rekognition services.

When I call any rekognition services it shows `Task timed out after 270.04 seconds`.But it works when I call locally using `serverless-offline-plugin`
I attach all necessary permissions to my `lambda` like `AmazonRekognitionFullAccess`

Here is my code

**index.js**

```
app.post('/myapi', function (req, res) {
    var params = {
        MaxResults: 3,
    };
    const rekognition = aws_config(); <-- rekognition configuration
    rekognition.listCollections(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err.stack);
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        }
        else{
            res.json(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});

function aws_config(){
    const $options = {
        'region'            : 'ap-southeast-2',
        'version'           : '2016-06-27',
        'accessKeyId '    : config.ENV.aws_key,
        'secretAccessKey ' : config.ENV.aws_secret,

    };
    return new AWS.Rekognition($options);
}
```

How to solve this timeout error as it doesn't show any error on `CloudWatch logs`?

Comment: You can use NAT Gateway to access your VPC resources and AWS services

Comment: ok i'll try and thank for your response

Comment: do you see the success in cloudwatch logs ? (this line's output       console.log(data);           // successful response)

Comment: @SébastienStormacq No its just a comment, in console it shows `timed out after 270.04 seconds`

Comment: I corrected my question now

Comment: Erm I haven't used serverless express, isn't that route just going to exit the function before res has been sent? Since you're not returning anything from that function until the the callback is executed? Try doing const results = await rekognition.listCollections(params).promise() - then log out the results. if that works lemmy know and I'll post a proper answer.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, firstly @MehmetOsmanoglu , I tried with NAT Gateway but it doesn't work , same timeout error occurred.

Comment: have a look this [guide](https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7)

Comment: @MrkFldig,I don't think so that route exit before execution because  'res' is used to respond to the api and I give a callback function as 2nd paramerter in `rekognition.listCollections` which in return give response from aws rekognition

Comment: @MehmetOsmanoglu, I tried your recommended guide but no luck , same error,

Comment: I think there is no problem in my code actually because i successfully test this offline with desired  output, may be something wrong with permissions or configuration. I should check again and let post answer later if solve.

Comment: Ahh I didn't think of that - sorry I missed the bit where you said it worked offline, as a test grant rekognition * in your Lambda's policy document see if that fixes it, locally Lambda's will use your credentials in ~.aws/credentials if you don't tell them otherwise.

Comment: @MrkFldig, I already done that  'rekognition:*'. i figured out my problem, Actually  it hangs because i connect my lambda with private subnet only i.e. only NAT gateway are connected , no igw connected, when i connect with public subnet i.e. one with igw , it worked , thanks to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcRKdEP94jM) video

Comment: Ahhh glad ya sorted it - I’ve forgotten about that a few times